# Node.js regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a problem with this code:

`var regex = new Regex(/test/);
console.log(regex.test("das ist ein test"));   // false??`

In fact I'm simply trying, to search a string in a string. It should be case insensitive. But none of my tried regexes worked yet.

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: You should use either native regex syntax: `var regex = /test/;` or (in this case unnecessary) the RegExp constructor with a **string** argument: `var regex = new RegExp("test");`

Answer (score 2):

```
var rx = /test/i;

console.log(rx.test("das ist ein test"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/test/);
```

Comment: How is this any different than what's in the OP?

Comment: Regex is not a native JS object, but RegExp is. Running the code with this modification actually does work.

Comment: @jehna1 ah, indeed. Apologies.

Comment: Regex --> RegExp. A missing p and the e is capitalized.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know there is a native RegExp in node. I used a module and required it under the name "Regex". Seems like the module is not working fine.